# vector scaling issues

Tags: java, math, vector, minecraft

Hello i am working on a minecraft bot that is based on the minecraft source-code and I needed to write a fly to block method... however my method seems to be glitching and I can't figure out why. Am i missing something? (sorry about the ambiguous naming, Local means it is the value local to the function, the local vector is actually stored in an array)

```
private void flyTo(int x, int y, int z,double posX,double posY,double posZ) {
    double xLocal = posX;
    double yLocal = posY;
    double zLocal = posZ;
    while(xLocal!=x &&yLocal!=y&&zLocal!=z){
        double[] v = new double[3];
        v[0] = x-xLocal;
        v[1] = y-yLocal;
        v[2] = z-zLocal;
        double magxz = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(v[0], 2)+Math.pow(v[2], 2));
        if(magxz>0.6D){
            double scaler = 0.6D/magxz;
            v[0] *= scaler;
            v[2] *= scaler;
        }
        if(Math.abs(v[1])>1){
            if(v[1]>0){
                v[1]=1;
            }else{
                v[1]=-1;
            }
        }
        xLocal+=v[0];
        yLocal+=v[1];
        zLocal+=v[2];
        mc.getSendQueue().addToSendQueue(new Packet11PlayerPosition((double)xLocal,(double)yLocal,yLocal+0.83,(double)zLocal,false));
        mc.getSendQueue().processReadPackets();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is going in strange directions or not moving at all and just generally not going where i tell it to...

Answer (score 1):

Without any more info, the only thing that I could suggest is to normalize `v`, as it seems like it is a direction vector:

```
v[0] = x-xLocal;
v[1] = y-yLocal;
v[2] = z-zLocal;

double mag = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(v[0], 2) + Math.pow(v[1], 2) + Math.pow(v[2], 2));

v[0] /= mag;
v[1] /= mag;
v[2] /= mag;
```